# Openvpn on Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, openvpn

I'm trying to install openvpn on a Windows 2003 Server with this configuration:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 192.168.111.0 255.255.255.0
ip-win32 dynamic
route-method exe
route-delay 10
tap-sleep 5
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Well. When the server goes up, I try to connect a client and it works! the problem is that when I try to ping from server to client or client to server there are no answer and when I try to go to a shared folder, it doesn't foudn anything.

Looking into the log I see this:

```
Sat Mar 19 10:27:06 2011 OpenVPN 2.1.4 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Nov  8 2010
Sat Mar 19 10:27:06 2011 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.222.99
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{310416B9-3D78-4777-8C0B-FD52C4823F49}.tap
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 TAP-Win32 Driver Version 9.7 
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 TAP-Win32 MTU=1500
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 192.168.111.1/255.255.255.252 on interface {310416B9-3D78-4777-8C0B-FD52C4823F49} [DHCP-serv: 192.168.111.2, lease-time: 31536000]
Sat Mar 19 10:27:07 2011 Sleeping for 10 seconds...
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 NOTE: FlushIpNetTable failed on interface [1966085] {310416B9-3D78-4777-8C0B-FD52C4823F49} (status=259) : No more data is available.  
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.111.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.111.2
The route addition failed: Either the interface index is wrong or the gateway does not lie on the same network as the interface. Check the IP Address Table for the machine.
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 IFCONFIG POOL: base=192.168.111.4 size=62
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Note this:
FlushIpNetTable failed on interface [1966085] {310416B9-3D78-4777-8C0B-FD52C4823F49} (status=259) : No more data is available.
    Sat Mar 19 10:27:17 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.111.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.111.2
    The route addition failed: Either the interface index is wrong or the gateway does not lie on the same network as the interface. Check the IP Address Table for the machine.

I think that the DHCP server on 192.168.111.2 doesn't go up, but I don't know why. Do you know what's wrong? I've seen that there are serveral people that on Windows 2003 server has the same problem. I have installed it on a windows xp and works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Google's public DNS in the "push dhcp-option DNS" lines, use the DNS server on your network.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but it makes the same =(